# How can we pass variable values at queue time to multi stage yaml build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to allow users to override some values of variables used in multistage yaml pipelines.
I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#allow-at-queue-time) and tried but it didn't work , i'm not sure if i'm using it correctly. There is no example available in docs as well.

Comment: well, what are you doing? what doesnt work? what is the error? etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify the variable in the YAML file's variables section. Author the whole workflow and save it. Then open the Variables tab of the build definition (this is in the UI), create the variable there, set a default value and check the 'allow at queue time'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went looking around everywhere in the docs but wasn't able to find it. It wasn't until I realized I had to click "Edit" then the variables tab for it to appear.